# Prism: How to remove existing View instance from memory

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

**Prism** usually keep the views in memory and load these views again when switching views using `RegionManager.RequestNavigate`.

I really like the fact that loading **existing views** in memory. But **at some point** I want to completely destroy (**Garbage Collected**) the existing view and want to load new fresh view.

**Example Scenario**

For example, there is a "CustomerList" view showing list of customers with email addresses. When I click on one customer in the list, new "SendEmail" View with populated email address will be loaded. When I click cancel, it will return back to "CustomerList" view.

When I click on the same customer in the list again, it will show the "SendEmail" view instance already existed in the memory.

But when I click on another customer in the list, the program should remove the existing "SendEmail" view instance in the memory and create new fresh "SendEmail" view with populated email address.

**Question**

I know it can be resolved with `IsNavigationTarget` method in the `INavigationAware` interface. But **Prism** just create the new "SendEmail" view instance and don't remove the existing "SendEmail" view from memory. In my assumption (not sure), creating new View instances (without removing old ones) will bloat the memory unnecessarily.

How should I solve this problem or is there other workarounds?

**Why `IRegionMemberLifetime` is not the answer?**

`KeepAlive` property of `IRegionMemberLifetime` can force the view to be deactivated and removed from the region when the view is navigated away from. But `KeepAlive` property is `readonly` property and have to set `true` or `false` since the creation of the View instance.

In my problem, I **don't want the view to be instantly removed** at once the view is navigated away from. *I still want to keep the view in the memory when the view is navigated away from. I only want to remove the view when I'm sure this view is not wanted anymore.*

Comment: What about IRegionMemberLifetime interface and KeepAlive property?

Comment: @galakt Please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you are asking is, "How can I have remove a View?". You don't know when to remove it, but when you are ready it needs to be removed?  In that case you need to manually remove the View from the Region.  One approach might be to use the EventAggregator to publish a RemoveEvent when you are ready to remove a view, and then respond to that.

Another option would be to create a custom region behavior to monitor the life cycle of the View and manage it that way.